# Dependency installation failed! error while deploying laravel api rest to heroku

Tags: php, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwFC2.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRoNO.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwFC2.png)

I get this error when I try to deploy my api rest laravel in heroku (when I run : git push heroku master ).there is any solution??

Comment: Have you tried to run composer install locally? Try to clone your repository into a new folder and run composer install. Is it throwing the same error on post-autoload-dump? What's the output of the package:discover command?

Comment: i tried what you said and the same error happened .

Comment: and the output of the package:discover command is :Discovered Package: facade/ignition Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel/passport
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/ui
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully

Comment: The command shows no error? Exits with code 1? Or 0?

Comment: the command of the package:discover is run successfully also composer install but git push heroku master show same error on post-autoload-dump

Comment: This is the error : Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
remote:  !     WARNING: A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!

Comment: Try to append `-vvv` to `@php artisan package:discover --ansi` to enable debug verbosity. If there’s an error something should be displayed.